# Modify array with Array.Foreach and lambda expression

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach, lambda

I'm trying to modify the values of the array but it doesn't get modified:

```
string buzones = File.ReadAllText("c:\\Buzones");
string[] buzoneslist = buzones.Split(',');

Array.ForEach(buzoneslist, x =>
{
    x = x.Replace(",", "");
});
```

It's like I'm doing a string.Replace without setting the resultant value to the
variable:

`s.replace(",", "");` instead of  `s=s.replace(",", "");`

Is it possible to accomplish inside a lambda expression?.

Comment: No, and it never will. Also, horrible style. Use `Select` instead and create a new array.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, you can't modify an array while you're enumerating it with `ForEach`, and strings are immutable so there's no function that will modify the instance in-place.

You could do either:

```
for (int i=0; i<buzoneslist.Length; i++) 
    buzoneslist[i] = buzoneslist[i].Replace(",", "");
```

Or:

```
buzoneslist = buzoneslist.Select(t => t.Replace(",", "")).ToArray();
```

I suppose if you really wanted to use a lambda, you could write an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static void ChangeEach<T>(this T[] array, Func<T,T> mutator) {
        for (int i=0; i<array.Length; i++) {
            array[i] = mutator(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

And then:

```
buzoneslist.ChangeEach(t => t.Replace(",", ""));
```